# Perl to count current value based on next value

Tags: perl, text, linear-algebra

Currently I'm learning Perl and gnuplot. I would like to know how to count certain value based on the next value. For example I have a text file consist of:

```
#ID(X) Y
1 1
3 9
5 11
```

The output should show the value of the unknown ID as well. So, the output should show:

```
#ID(X) Y
1 1
2 5
3 9
4 10
5 11
```

The Y of ID#2 is based on the following:
((2-3)/(1-3))*1 + ((2-1)/(3-1))*9 which is linear algebra

```
Y2=((X2-X3)/(X1-X3))*Y1 + ((X2-X1)/(X3-X1)) * Y3
```

Same goes to ID#5

Currently I have this code,

```
    #! /usr/bin/perl -w
    use strict;

    my $prev_id = 0;
    my $prev_val = 0;
    my $next_id;
    my $next_val;

    while (<>)
    {
    my ($id, $val) = split;
    for (my $i = $prev_id + 1; $i < $next_id; $i++)
    {
    $val = (($id - $next_id) / ($prev_id - $next_id)) * $prev_val + (($id - $prev_id) / ($next_id - $prev_id)) * $next_val;
    printf ("%d %s\n", $i, $val);
    }
    printf ("%d %s\n", $id, $val);
    ($prev_val, $prev_id) = ($val, $id);
    ($next_val, $next_id) = ($prev_val, $prev_id);  
}
```

Comment: Again? Where's your effort? What part are you having a problem with?

Comment: @ikegami, I'm having a problem to get my next value. here is my effort

Comment: #! /usr/bin/perl -w use strict; my $prev_id = 0; my $prev_val = 0; my $next_id; my $next_val; while (<>) { my ($id, $val) = split; for (my $i = $prev_id + 1; $i < $id; $i++) { $val = (($id - $next_id) / ($prev_id - $next_id)) * $prev_val + (($id - $prev_id) / ($next_id - $prev_id)) * $next_val; printf ("%d %s\n", $i, $val); } printf ("%d %s\n", $id, $val); ($prev_val, $prev_id) = ($val, $id); }

Answer (score 1):

Your formula seems more complicated than I would expect, given that you are always dealing with integer spacings of 1.

You did not say whether you want to fill gaps for multiple consecutive missing values, but let's assume you want to.

What you do is read in the first line, and say that's the current one and you output it.  Now you read the next line, and if its ID is not the expected one, you fill the gaps with simple linear interpolation...

Pseudocode

```
(currID, currY) = readline()
outputvals( currID, currY )

while lines remain do
    (nextID, nextY) = readline()
    gap = nextID - currID

    for i = 1 to gap
        id = currID + i
        y = currY + (nextY - currY) * i / gap
        outputvals( id, y )
    end

    (currID, currY) = (nextID, nextY)
end
```

Sorry for the non-Perl code.  It's just that I haven't been using Perl for ages, and can't remember half of the syntax. =)  The concepts here are pretty easy to translate into code though.

Comment: This is what I have for current 
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $prev_id = 0;
my $prev_val = 0;
my $next_id;
my $next_val;

while (<>)
{
my ($id, $val) = split;
for (my $i = $prev_id + 1; $i < $id; $i++)
{
$val = (($id - $next_id) / ($prev_id - $next_id)) * $prev_val + (($id - $prev_id) / ($next_id - $prev_id)) * $next_val;
printf ("%d %s\n", $i, $val);
}
printf ("%d %s\n", $id, $val);
($prev_val, $prev_id) = ($val, $id);
}

But how to declare the next value???

Comment: The 'next' value is actually the one you just read in.  I suppose that instead of using the terms "current" and "next", I could have used "previous" and "current".

Comment: Why won't you use my linear interpolation formula?  You're using that over-generalised one that boils down to exactly the same thing.  You also should loop with `<=` not `<` or you won't output the values for the current line.  That means you'll only output interpolated values and none of the actual ones.  Finally, if you insist on that particular formula, then please pass the correct values into it.  Look at your description of the formula, then look at your code, then look at where (or if) you are calculating each variable that goes into it.

Comment: The problem is i do not know how to pass the first line as prev_prev_value and the second line as prev_value. I mean I understand your pseudocode but i am not able to transform it to become a perl code.

Comment: Just set a flag to say it's your first time around the loop.  If it is, set the prev values to the ones you just `split` out, clear the flag and call `next` to go round the loop again.

Answer (score 0):

You indicated your problem is getting the next value. The key isn't to look ahead, it's to look behind.

```
my $prev = get first value;
my ($prev_a, $prev_b) = parse($prev);

my $this = get second value;
my ($this_a, $this_b) = parse($this);

while ($next = get next value) {
   my ($next_a, $next_b) = parse($next);
   ...
   $prev = $this;  $prev_a = $this_a;  $prev_b = $this_b;  
   $this = $next;  $this_a = $next_a;  $this_b = $next_b;
}
```

Comment: Yes... you are correct. The key is as long as you have two values which is previous ID and previous previous ID, you will check between the previous ID and previous previous ID, if there is a value drop, it will reform back the value. I get it. But my coding mind is weak... >.<

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Let me pluralise that for you

Comment: You have 3 id vars and 3 val vars in your code. That makes no sense.

Comment: 3 id vars are for the prev id, prev prev id and the current id that need to be reformed. 3 val vars are for the prev value, prev prev value and the current value that need to be reformed...

Comment: So you need to look at three records at once? So you need to remember the last two records, then, and do this->prev and next->this. I've already spent too much time on this. You really need to work on your questions.

Comment: You don't get any records before the loop. As I showed, looking back requires having something to look back to.

Answer (score 0):

Using an array may be the way to go. This will also make your data available for further manipulation.

** Caveat: will not work for multiple consecutive missing values of y; see @paddy's answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @coordinates;
while (<DATA>) {
    my ($x, $y) = split;
    $coordinates[$x] = $y;
}

# note that the for loop starts on index 1 here ...
for my $x (1 .. $#coordinates) {
    if (! $coordinates[$x]) {
        $coordinates[$x] = (($x - ($x + 1)) / (($x - 1) - ($x + 1)))
                         * $coordinates[$x - 1]
                         + (($x - ($x - 1)) / (($x + 1) - ($x - 1)))
                         * $coordinates[$x + 1];
    }

    print "$x - $coordinates[$x]\n";
}

__DATA__
1 1
3 9
5 11
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my @in = (1,9,11);
my @out;

for (my $i = 0; $i<$#in; $i++) {

    my $j = $i*2;

    my $X1 = $i;
    my $X2 = $i+1;
    my $X3 = $i+2;

    my $Y1 = $in[$i];
    my $Y3 = $in[$i+1];

    my $Y2 = $Y1*(($X2-$X3)/($X1-$X3))
           + $Y3*(($X2-$X1)/($X3-$X1));

    $out[$j]   = $in[$i];
    $out[$j+1] = $Y2;
}

$out[$#in*2] = $in[$#in];
print (join " ",@out);
```

Comment: why the downvote? This is not as generalised as @paddy's answer but it does produce the correct result, it is faithful to the form of the question, and it is well-formed Perl.

Comment: It doesn't explain how it works and how it differs from the OP's code. I would assume that's why you got downvoted (but I'm not the one who did it).

Comment: @preaction, thanks for your comment. When I posted this answer, OP didn't _have_ any code. Toni added it 3 hours later. From the original question it appeared that Toni had trouble envisioning how to turn the problem into perl, so I made an answer which was a direct, working, perl transcription of the problem. I am not claiming it's a genius answer, just objecting to downvote actions on answers that are _not wrong_. Particularly when downvoter leaves no comment as to why.